# How to share code between python projects?

Tags: python-3.x, shared-libraries

Let's say that I have two projects with the following structure:

/project1
 
/project2

Now I have developed a function/class that could be useful to the both projects. I would like to put it somewhere out of the project1/project2 directories and to maintain it as a separate project. 
So I probably need structure like this:

/project1
/project2
/shared

If I put my helper functions/classes in the project that will be in the shared folder, how to use them from project1/project2?

At the moment my option is to use sys.path.append('/shared') in project1/project2 and after it to do import(s) from shared folder.

Is there some more pythonic way to do the same?

Comment: Why do not you create a libraries?

Comment: Let's say that I have a MyModule in shared folder in which is a class MyClass definition:

/project1
/project2
/shared/MyModule(MyClass)

How to create a subclass of MyClass in Project1/Project2 folders?

Answer (score 8):

You can import /shared using parent module, as long as the parent module is in PYTHONPATH. If your project would look like:

```
toplevel_package/
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
└── project1
    ├── __init__.py
    └── foo.py
└── project2
    ├── __init__.py
    └── bar.py
└── shared
    ├── __init__.py
    └── save_files.py
```

Then imports would look like:

```
from toplevel_package.shared import save_files
```

This works as long as toplevel_package is in your PYTHONPATH. Either:

1. Only launch toplevel_package scripts (which can then call subpackages)
2. Move toplevel_package module to any folder listed in PYTHONPATH
3. Add toplevel_package to PYTHONPATH

More info can be found in [import from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951255/import-script-from-a-parent-directory/8951269).

You could also simply use [import using full path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path), which is not as *pythonic* in my opinion but works well in some situations (in the end, .

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I am now using PYTHONPATH and directory structure as you have suggested and everything works well. Thanks