# How do i import a function from a file in a parent directory

Tags: python, import, directory

I have a pycharm project with one python file called main.py

on my desktop i have a folder called 'Python'
inside it looks like this:

```
 - Desktop
    - framework.py
    - Python
        - Python Projects
            - Project File
                - main.py
```

In my main file i want to import a function from the framework file.
for example if my framework file looks like this:

```
def print_hi():
    print("hi")
```

how would i import the function into my main file?

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8951563/15400163

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the python structure for import, you should use system layout I mean:

```
parent/
    __init__.py
    one/
        __init__.py
    two/
        __init__.py
    three/
        __init__.py
```

so first of all use **init** file the simply use **import**

Answer (score 0):

1. Use sys module and set the path directly to the required module.

```
sys.path.append('add_path_here')
```

2. use sys module as well as the path module for getting the directory and set the path directly to the required module

Example,

```
directory = path.path(__file__).abspath()
sys.path.append(directory.parent.parent)
```